# Расчёт % в калькуляторе в зависимости от значения переменной

Tags: javascript, html

Всем доброго дня!
Прошу помочь в реализации калькулятора.
Задача следующая:
Есть две переменных ("bumaga" - материал; "tiraj" - кол-во материала), первая умножается на вторую, но в зависимости от кол-ва тиража (материала), применяется скидка.
Загвоздка в том, что у каждого материала при одинаковом тираже будет своя скидка (для понимания прикладываю прайс).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сейчас в переменной "result" корректно считается только материал "Картон, 300 гр, 4+0", как сделать, чтобы в зависимости от выбора материала скидка рассчитывалась по своему алгоритму для каждого материала?
Заранее спасибо за подсказку.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Калькулятор</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    /*
     * Функция подсчета стоимости 
     */
    function calc() {
      //получаем ссылку на элемент Select (Бумага)
      var bumaga = document.getElementById("bumaga");
      //получаем ссылку на элемент Select (Двухсторонняя ламинация)
      var laminat = document.getElementById("laminat");
      //получаем ссылку на элемент Select (Тираж)
      var kolvo = document.getElementById("kolvo");
      //получаем ссылку на элемент span, в него будем писать стоимость тиража
      var result = document.getElementById("result");

      //передаём в пустую переменную тираж кол-во визиток
      var tiraj = 0;
      tiraj += parseFloat(kolvo.options[kolvo.selectedIndex].value);

      //подсчитываем общую стоимость одной визитки 
      var price = 0;
      price += parseFloat(bumaga.options[bumaga.selectedIndex].value);
      price += parseFloat(laminat.options[laminat.selectedIndex].value);

      //в зависимости от тиража перемножаем переменные прайс и тираж с учетом скидки и выводим стоимость
      result.innerHTML = Math.floor((tiraj >= 1 && tiraj < 289) ? price * tiraj :
        (tiraj >= 312 && tiraj < 529) ? price * tiraj / 100 * 76 :
        (tiraj >= 552 && tiraj < 1009) ? price * tiraj / 100 * 64 :
        (tiraj >= 1032 && tiraj < 2017) ? price * tiraj / 100 * 48 :
        'Сбой!');
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <b><h2>Выберите параметры заказа:</b></h2>
  <br>
  <b>Материал:</b><br>
  <select onchange="calc()" id="bumaga">
    <option value="2.5">Картон, 300 гр, 4+0</option>
    <option value="3">Картон, 300 гр, 4+4</option>
    <option value="2.7">Color Copy, 300 гр, 4+0</option>
    <option value="3.2">Color Copy, 300 гр, 4+4</option>
    <option value="2.8">Color Copy, 350 гр, 4+0</option>
    <option value="3.3">Color Copy, 350 гр, 4+4</option>
    <option value="5">Маджестик, 4+0</option>
    <option value="6.5">Маджестик, 4+4</option>
    <option value="4">Лён, 4+0</option>
    <option value="5">Лён, 4+4</option>
  </select><br><br>

  <b>Двухсторонняя ламинация:</b><br>
  <select onchange="calc()" id="laminat">
    <option value="0">Нет</option>
    <option value="1.2">Глянцевая 32 мк</option>
    <option value="1.8">Глянцевая 75 мк</option>
    <option value="3.5">Глянцевая 125 мк</option>
    <option value="6.4">Глянцевая 250 мк</option>
  </select><br><br>

  <b>Тираж:</b><br>
  <select onchange="calc()" id="kolvo">
    <option value="96">96</option>
    <option value="120">120</option>
    <option value="144">144</option>
    <option value="192">192</option>
    <option value="240">240</option>
    <option value="264">264</option>
    <option value="288">288</option>
    <option value="408">408</option>
    <option value="480">480</option>
    <option value="504">504</option>
    <option value="600">600</option>
    <option value="696">696</option>
    <option value="792">792</option>
    <option value="888">888</option>
    <option value="912">912</option>
    <option value="984">984</option>
    <option value="1008">1008</option>
    <option value="1512">1512</option>
    <option value="1608">1608</option>
    <option value="1704">1704</option>
    <option value="1800">1800</option>
    <option value="1896">1896</option>
    <option value="1992">1992</option>
    <option value="2016">2016</option>
  </select><br><br>

  <h3><b>Стоимость тиража: <span id="result">____</span> руб.</b></h3>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ясно если прайс различный то и считать нужно отдельно покомпонентно, а не так как у вас

```
 var price = 0;
 price += parseFloat(bumaga.options[bumaga.selectedIndex].value);
 price += parseFloat(laminat.options[laminat.selectedIndex].value);
```

исправте на

```
 var priceBumaga = 0;
 priceBumaga += parseFloat(bumaga.options[bumaga.selectedIndex].value);

 var priceLaminat = 0;
 priceLaminat += parseFloat(laminat.options[laminat.selectedIndex].value);
```

и вычисляете каждый отдельно со своей скидкой

```
priceTotal =  priceBumaga * tiraj * tirajBumagaKoef + priceLaminat * tiraj * tirajLaminatKoef
```

где
`tirajBumagaKoef, tirajLaminatKoef` - соответствующие коэфиценты материала к тиражу

Comment: А как в result вывести расчет именно по тому материалу, который выбран в переменной "bumaga"? Мой пример не работает...
`            result.innerHTML = Math.floor ((bumaga = 2.5) ? priceTotal :
     (bumaga = 3) ? priceTotal1 :
            (bumaga = 2.7) ? priceTotal2 :
     (bumaga = 3.2) ? priceTotal3 :
     (bumaga = 3.2) ? priceTotal4);`

Comment: Я указал разделить на 2 части по материалам. откуда у вас total3

Comment: Согласно предложенному вами варианту, для переменной priceBumaga всегда будет применяться один и тот-же коэффициент. В файле, который я приложил, каждая вертикальная колонка считается по своему алгоритму. Я подумал сделать несколько переменных priceTotal (отдельная переменная для каждой колонки/материала), но теперь вопрос в том, как выводить в result нужную переменную?

Comment: но у вас же только один в выборе. Я из-за этого говорил только для 2 опций. Если вам нужно также в несколько колонок то, да считайте с дополнительными переменными

Comment: Каким способом можно определить, какой материал выбран в переменной бумага?

Comment: Выс на самом деле путает, то что вы пытаетесь выбирать слишком много когда у вас есть зависимости. Не получится выбрать маленький тираж и максимальную скидку

Comment: Отсюда следует что если пользователь выбрал тираж. то понятно что бумага, остается выбирать качество и ламинацию